# How do I get the value of a checkbox from the Gravity Forms Entry Object?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This seems like it should be a fairly easy question, but Google is not yielding results.

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that processes data from Gravity Forms after the submission is complete. I'm using the `gform_after_submission` hook.

This passes an "Entry Object" to my function for processing. Most of the values I can extract just fine. So for example:

`$eventDate = $e[2];`

...Works just fine. This is a date field. All I have to do is pull the value out of the entry object with the proper index.

My issue is getting the value of a particular checkbox. I need to see if it was checked or not.

This doesn't work:

`$checkbox = $e[4];`

I'm guessing it's because a checkbox field can have multiple values. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get to the value of each specific checkbox.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no checkbox value is set manually, the variable will have the value "on". Please do a var_dump($e); and post the result.

Comment: Got it... the var_dump explained it. You get to the value by doing

$checkbox = $e["4.1"];

I'm guessing if there's multiple values in the field you increase the second number sequentially.