# Wordpress Gravity Forms e-mail notification not sending checkbox values

Tags: wordpress, email, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to send e-mail notification to user when form is  submitted. All input field values are sent, but not checkbox values. To get values from input boxes, I use {Field label: ID} , but for checkboxes it sends an empty value via e-mail.

I have 4 checkboxes and the field is called Lisad with ID 11. Shouldn't I be useing {Lisad:11} to get the value and send it via e-mail?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513180/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-checkbox-from-the-gravity-forms-entry-object?rq=1) will help?

Answer (score 0):

Check-boxes can described in one of two ways: [**value** and **checked-ness**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> `checkbox:` A check box. **You must use the `value` attribute to define the value submitted by this item. Use the `checked` attribute to indicate whether this item is selected.** You can also use the `indeterminate` attribute to indicate that the checkbox is in an indeterminate state (on most platforms, this draws a horizontal line across the checkbox).

Un-ticked checkboxes [do not have their value sent](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) when a form is submitted:

> The HTML specification says **unchecked check boxes are not successful, and thus web browsers do not send them.** Unfortunately this introduces a gotcha: if an `Invoice` model has a `paid` flag, and in the form that edits a paid invoice the user unchecks its check box, no paid parameter is sent.

Ruby on Rails has a work-around for this, which you may be able to use:

> To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden field before the very check box. The hidden field has the same name and its attributes mimic an unchecked check box.
>
> This way, the client either sends only the hidden field (representing the check box is unchecked), or both fields. Since the HTML specification says key/value pairs have to be sent in the same order they appear in the form, and parameters extraction gets the last occurrence of any repeated key in the query string, that works for ordinary forms.